# Check/Uncheck ToolBarButton on Property Changed

Tags: c#

hi i have property named.

```
public bool ShowLabels{get; set;}
```

and one toolbar menu button to set/unset ShowLabels value

i wants that when value of ShowLabels property changed it also change the check state of menu item button. how i can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a real private variable for showLabels, and expand the `get;` and `set;` to be a method that does the opertation you require:

```
private bool showLabels;
public bool ShowLabels
{
    get {return this.showLabels; }
    set {
        toolbaritem.property = !toolbaritem.property;
        this.showlabels = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also setting the value of ShowLabels from click event of toolbar item.

Comment: This would use that same functionality - your `ShowLabels = true` would call this setter which would affect the checkbox appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an 'auto' property, write your own property accessors to change the check state of the menu buttons.